# Elliptic curve cryptography for ActionScript

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, encryption, elliptic-curve

Does anyone know if there is a (preferably efficient :-) ) implementation of elliptic curve cryptography for ActionScript?

The only library I know of is [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/), which offers great implementations for symmetric cryptography, hashing and several other cryptography-related operations, but it has only RSA for public key cryptography.

Thanks in advance,
Jan

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no other competent cryptographic library. For a project I made a quick port of as3crypto over to Haxe so it could use Alchemy memory, and in some test cases it was around 20x faster. It was just a quick port tho.

I created a few months ago this feature request:

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-6440

However it doesn't seem to have caught any attention even if I think it's something vital.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a library that implements a lot of cryptographic algorithms including the Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) algorithm: [http://code.google.com/p/flame](http://code.google.com/p/flame/). All algorithms are compatible with .NET Framework and have nearly the same API as .NET ones.